# psycopg2 Copy_From with Different Null Data types

Tags: psycopg2

I am trying to import an employee list with null values; however there are date/time nulls as well as varchar/text.  It looks like it's trying to insert a string in any of the date/time fields if its null and this is throwing an error.  How do I get around this?  Any feedback is greatly appreciated.

The error:
psycopg2.errors.InvalidDatetimeFormat: invalid input syntax for type date: ""
CONTEXT:  COPY aides_hcs, line 5, column first_work_date: ""

My code:

```
import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect(host="192.168.0.250",database="People", user="hcsadmin", password="Temp@2018")
cur = conn.cursor()
with open('C:\Reports\Data_Files\HCS\Active_Employees.csv', 'r') as f:
    cur.copy_from(f,'aides_hcs',sep=',', null='None')
conn.commit()

cur.close
conn.close
```

Comment: Can you please add the header data from the csv and one sample row from the csv to your question?

That way I can test it on my computer